# Is it possible to create EC2 instance from describe_instances() output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

Using python and BOTO3 service there is an option to use [describe_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) to get all the information about the running instances in specific region.

If I use that and save the output in JSON, later input that json and pass it to [create_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances), is it going to work or the format is different from what I need to pass to [create_instnaces()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) function?

I'm asking that because I would like to make an automated option to get back a terminated instance which I have all its information saved.

thanks!

Comment: A general suggestion is to add hyperlinks to API you're mentioning in a question to make it easier for those trying to help you on the issue

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov Done =)

Comment: Have you tried just doing it? What were the results or specific problems? The documentation is quite clear on exactly the arguments that `create_instances` expects. Even if there is a mismatch in the arguments, it will be quite straightforward to map only the arguments that are needed.

Comment: Have you considered a [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html)?

Comment: @dmutler I've tried to run this, yes there is a mismatch of the format and some of the arguments need to be adjusted in order to be passed properly to create_instances.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard format that would allow easy creation of a new instance from an existing or terminated instance.

You would need to take the output of `describe_instances()` and use it to call `run_instances()`.

Some information might no longer be available from a terminated instance, such as User Data.

Comment: it seems like you are right, just the output need to be adjusted for the run_instances()/create_instances() functions